# swiper js dosn't work with next.js v 12.1.4?

Tags: next.js, swiper.js

my slider component does not recognize the swipe and click on the swiper and any action dosn't work on them.I don't know what is the problem here.

here is my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "next": "12.1.4",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "swiper": "^8.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "17.0.23",
    "@types/react": "17.0.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.14",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.30.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.30.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript-prettier": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^11.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.25.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "sass": "^1.49.11",
    "typescript": "4.6.3"
  }
```

and here is my swiper component :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigation, Autoplay, Pagination } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/autoplay';
import 'swiper/css/effect-fade';

interface ISliderItem {
  key: string; //
  image: string;
}

const Slider: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const items: ISliderItem[] = [
    { key: '1', image: '/logo.svg' },
    { key: '2', image: '/logo.svgi' },
    { key: '3', image: '/logo.svgj' },
    { key: '4', image: '/logo.svgm' },
    { key: '5', image: '/logo.svgm' },
    { key: '6', image: '/logo.svg,' },
  ];
  return (
    <Swiper
      navigation
      modules={[Navigation, Autoplay, Pagination]}
      centeredSlides
      autoplay={{
        delay: 4000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
      }}
    >
      {items.map(item => (
        <SwiperSlide
          key={item.key}
          style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${item.image})`, width: '100%', height: '200px' }}
        >
          <p>{item.image}</p>
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}
    </Swiper>
  );
};
export default Slider;
```

this exact code works in my ther next js projects but it dosn't work here in my new project with next js version 12

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y,  Autoplay  } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/scrollbar';

export default function SwiperPage(){

const items = [
{ key: '1', image: '/logo.svg' },
{ key: '2', image: '/logo.svgi' },
{ key: '3', image: '/logo.svgj' },
{ key: '4', image: '/logo.svgm' },
{ key: '5', image: '/logo.svgm' },
{ key: '6', image: '/logo.svg,' },
];
return(
 <Swiper
        // install Swiper modules
        modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y, Autoplay]}
        spaceBetween={50}
        slidesPerView={1}
        autoplay={
          {delay: 5000}
        }
      >
      {items.map(item => (
       <SwiperSlide
        key={item.key}
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${item.image})`, width: '100%', height: '200px' }}
    >
        <p>{item.image}</p>
       </SwiperSlide>
  ))}
  </Swiper>
  )
}
```

Here is basic example adapted to your `items` - works with nextjs v12